# Strategy for Plasma Passion Version 3 mission

Tags: achievements, raiden-v-directors-cut

As titled, does anyone already completed the last mission Plasma Passion Version 3? I stuck on the Humpty Dumpty second form and only I know is how to avoid its first winding bullet attack of its 2nd phase. I expect to beat its second form by using one cheer call and one bomb. But this guy seems has more HP with plasma attack. I am looking for a strategy to clear this mission.

Comment: @Skye-AT Wow, Thanks for create a new tag for me